# Load spinner with with objects and strings

Tags: java, android

This is my `Spinner` code that loads employee names from my SQL db as objects and displays them on screen:

```
private void loadNames() {
    //database handler
    LysandrosDatabaseAdapter db = new LysandrosDatabaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    List<DataBean> list = db.getAllDat();

    //list for storing the names
    String[] nameList = new String[list.size()];
    //list for storing the ID and keeping it hidden
    employeeList = new int[list.size()];
    //loop to fill the list

    nameList[0] = "All Employees";
    employeeList[0] = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        nameList[i+1] = list.get(i).getName() + " " + list.get(i).getSurname();
        employeeList[i+1] = list.get(i).getID();
    }
    //creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String > dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameList);
    //drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice);
    //attaching data adapter to spinner
    selectName.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

I'm trying to include a text reading "All Employees" as the first option because I want to implement an `If` statement that when users select the option "All Employees" the app will fetch some particular data and when users select a specific employee, e.g. "John Smith" the app will fetch data only for that record.

The snippet above is what I've come to so far and I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

My LogCat shows this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lysandroslysandrou.marstest4/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.marstest4.Reports}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
        at com.example.lysandroslysandrou.marstest4.Reports.loadNames(Reports.java:147)
        at com.example.lysandroslysandrou.marstest4.Reports.onCreate(Reports.java:78)
```

Line 147 is `nameList[i+1] = list.get(i).getName() + " " + list.get(i).getSurname();`

I've tried many other methods but none of them worked. Loading a value saved as "All Employees" from my db is also not a viable solution.

**I'm looking for two things:**

**A)** Why am I getting this error particularly in my case? (I've read about this exception [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) but can't understand why it's happening here)

and **B)** Is there a solution to my problem?

**NOTE**: If lines `nameList[0] = "All Employees` and `employeeList[0] = "0"` are removed the snippet works fine.

**EDIT:** My new stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(AppCompatSpinner.java:624)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(AppCompatSpinner.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.compatMeasureContentWidth(AppCompatSpinner.java:547)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.access$500(AppCompatSpinner.java:65)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth(AppCompatSpinner.java:738)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:763)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:424)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**EDIT 2:** This is my `onItemSelected` method:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //On selecting a spinner item
    String list = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    //employeeId = employeeList[position];
    //showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
//list for storing the names
String[] nameList = new String[list.size()];
//list for storing the ID and keeping it hidden
employeeList = new int[list.size()];
```

to

```
//list for storing the names
String[] nameList = new String[list.size() + 1];
//list for storing the ID and keeping it hidden
employeeList = new int[list.size() + 1];
```

because you need to allocate one more item for the first "All employees" element.

And you're getting an exсeption when try to access `namesList[i + 1]` element, when `i == list.size() - 1`, so `i + 1 == list.size()`. For example, access `namesList[5]`, when you've allocated only `0..4` elements with `String[] nameList = new String[list.size()];`

I commented some lines, because I doesn't have you db. But the follwing code works fine for me:

```
private void loadSpinner(Spinner spinner, ArrayList<Integer> items) {
    //list for storing the names
    String[] nameList = new String[items.size() + 1];
    //list for storing the ID and keeping it hidden
    //employeeList = new int[list.size()];
    //loop to fill the list

    nameList[0] = "All Employees";
    //employeeList[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        nameList[i + 1] = String.valueOf(i);
    }
    //creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameList);
    //drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice);
    //attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but now I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference` when I click on my spinner!

Comment: That piece of code works fine for me, so NullPointerException is caused with another part. Can you post more code and a new stacktrace?

Comment: Yea iof course, I added the new stacktrace but what more code do you want?

Comment: I've included more code, please tell me if that is useful to you or if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Hm.. I've tried onItemSelected also and all works fine for me. The only difference for me is that I've changed `list.get(i).getName() + " " + list.get(i).getSurname();` to `String.valueOf(i);`. Can you try to replace this and run?

Comment: Can you post the entire function please?

Comment: Omg It worked, thank you so much. Instead of having `nameList[i + 1]` I had `nameList[i]` ! Again, thank you